# Can't override UserCreateSerializer in Djoser

Tags: python, authentication, serialization, django-rest-framework, djoser

I'm building an application using Django Rest Framework(DRF) in which I'm using Djoser library for user authentication processes. I'm currently facing issues in overriding the default Djoser UserCreateSerializer. I wanted an OTP to be sent to the user's phone number whenever they post on the `auth/users` endpoint and that's why decided to override the default UserCreateSerializer's `perform_create` method.

I tried extending the default UserCreateSerializer that Djoser provides and writing my custom functionality under the Serializer's perform_create method. My implementation is as follows:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser, BaseModel):
    """
    User model with inherited Abstract User
    """
    MALE_TYPE = 'M'
    FEMALE_TYPE = 'F'
    OTHER_TYPE = 'O'
    GENDERS = (
        (MALE_TYPE, 'Male'),
        (FEMALE_TYPE, 'Female'),
        (OTHER_TYPE, 'Other'),
    )

    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(('email address'), unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    DOB = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    CNIC = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images/', null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices = GENDERS, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True, blank=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=ref_code)
    confirm_slug = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    verify_slug = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    delete_slug = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'DOB', 'CNIC', 'gender',]

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)
```

Custom User Manager:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    use_in_migrations = True
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

serializers.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import transaction
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserCreateSerializer, PasswordRetypeSerializer
from djoser import utils

from .utils import send_otp

class UserCreateSerializer(BaseUserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseUserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ['id', 'username','first_name','last_name', 'gender',]

    
    def perform_create(self, validated_data):
        with transaction.atomic():
            user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
            print('perform_create @UserSerializer running...')
            send_otp(self.context['request'] ,validated_data['phone'])
            print('OTP sent.')
            if settings.SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL:
                user.is_active = False
                user.save(update_fields=["is_active"])
        return user
```

I followed the Djoser documentation for overriding the default serializer and added the path of the custom UserCreateSerializer to the Djoser dict in settings.py as follows:

settings.py:

```
DJOSER = {
    "LOGIN_FIELD": "email",
    "USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True,
    "USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION": True,
    "PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION": True,
    "SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL": True,
    "SET_USERNAME_RETYPE": True,
    "SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_SHOW_EMAIL_NOT_FOUND': True,
    "PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL": "reset_password_confirm/{uid}/{token}/",
    "USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL": "email_reset_confirm/{uid}/{token}",
    "SERIALIZERS": {
        "user_create":"core.serializers.UserCreateSerializer",
        "current_user": "core.serializers.UserSerializer",
        "user":"core.serializers.UserSerializer",
        "password_reset_confirm":"core.serializers.CustomPasswordResetConfirmSerializer"
    },
    'EMAIL': {
        'confirmation': 'management.email.ConfirmationEmail',
    }
}
```

However, when I access the `auth/users` endpoint for user registration, it uses the default user registration serializer provided by Djoser. What am I doing wrong? Is there some problem with my implementation? I also implemented a custom password reset confirm serializer and that seems to work well, however, the UserCreateSerializer implementation is not working.

Here's my views and urls.py files:

Views:

```
class CustomUserViewSet(BaseUserViewSet):

    @action(["post"], detail=False, renderer_classes=[TemplateHTMLRenderer])
    def reset_password_confirm(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = CustomPasswordResetConfirmSerializer(
            data=request.data,
            context={
                'view': self,
                'request': request
            }
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        if djoser_settings.PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION:
            context = {'user': serializer.save()}
            to = [get_user_email(serializer.instance)]
            djoser_settings.EMAIL.password_changed_confirmation(
                self.request, context).send(to)
        return TemplateResponse(request, template='management\ResetPasswordConfirmTemplate.html')

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {
            'request': self.request
        }
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('__debug__/', include('debug_toolbar.urls')),
    path('customers/', include('customers.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
]
```

Comment: Is `core` application is in `INSTALLED_APP` (settings.py)